# PrimeFaces calendar has old value in onblur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I'm trying to copy calendar's value into inputText field (don't ask me why) in the following way:

```
<p:calendar id="cal" widgetVar="calWidget" 
    onblur="PF('inputWidget').val(PF('calWidget').val());"/>
<p:inputText id="text" widgetVar="inputWidget" />
```

I've overridden PF functions, that's all working fine, the problem is that inputText gets previous selected date i.e. inputText is always one step behind with values. Is this expected behaviour and does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

P.S. I tried simpler solution also, same thing happens:

```
onblur="PF('inputWidget').val(this.value);"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dateSelect` event:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:calendar value="#{myDate}">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="dateOutput" />
        </p:calendar>
        <p:inputText id="dateOutput" value="#{myDate}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, can't say this don't work so i'll accept your answer ofcourse. I'm just not sure why i can't easily do this on clientside, with something like ondateselect. But i have to admit i'm not happy with using this in my **particular** case but that's not your concern. :) Thanks.